# How to exclude group for calculations

Tags: reporting-services

I am new to SSRS, Can any one explain how to solve the below problem below in SSRS

I have data like below

[image]

In my Report I need to calculate the values like below

[image]

Here the value 181 is the sum of all countries.  When I took country as a first column measure is grouping by country, but in the denominator I should exclude the grouping.

It is possible to do this at SSRS level instead of query level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to include multiple expressions in the same text box.  this is what you can do here to show both the values.

1. After your existing expression just type a '/' in the text box.
2. Then create a new placeholder in the textbox add a new expression as follows

   ```
   =Sum(CInt(Fields!Val.Value), "DataSet1")
   ```

   (Note I have included a `CInt` as my values were returned as text.  `DataSet1` is the name of my Dataset)

As a result, in Design View my chart looks like this

[image]

And when run, like this

[image]

Hopefully his is what you need, but if not, please let me know and I can try to assist further.